# Apex test classes query with testclasses name apex classes name

Tags: apex, unit-test

We are using following query :

```
SELECT ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ASC
```

Is there any query where we can see, Apexclass with there testclasses name which cover them and % covered

Comment: These are not the regular Sobjects to get the data via SOQL using APEX..
So you need to send an request to Tooling API to get the information what ever you want from APEX. Below is the sample code that I used to get the custom object ID via Tooling API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not the regular Sobjects to get the data via SOQL using APEX..
So you need to send an request to Tooling API to get the information what ever you want from APEX. Below is the sample code that I used to get the custom object ID via Tooling API.

```
String objectIdQuery = 'select Id from CustomObject where DeveloperName = \'' + objectName + '\'';

String environmentURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/tooling/query/?q=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(objectIdQuery, 'UTF-8');

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setEndpoint(environmentURL);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    Http h = new Http();
    return h.send(req).getBody();
```

Comment: Are you sure the Tooling API offers that information? A link to the relevant API would make that clearer.

Comment: Here is the link for supported objects in tooling API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm